# Regex to extract if match occurs within first N characters

Tags: regex

I am new to regex still in learning phase. I wrote an regex expression to extract until first occurrence of a colon:

```
^([^:]+):
```

Now I want to take it one step further and limit the search to within first 100 characters.  Which mean no match if match does not occur within first 100 characters and I don't know how to amend this expression to do the needful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
^([^:]{1,100}):
```

This regex matches all text from the start of line/text to the first colon only if there is 1–100 characters before the colon (`{1,100}` instead of `+`).

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
(?!^[^:]{100})(^[^:]+):$
```

https://regex101.com/r/dBOzVT/2

Comment: @Amer.. could you please check this solution as well